# How do i add +30 everytime when user click on plus button?

Tags: java, android, for-loop

For the first item the total is 49, but I want to add 30 every time the user clicks on the button.

```
1st item: 49
2nd item: 79
3rd item: 109
```

and so on.

I have tried this but it's not working:

```
for (int i =49;i<9;i=i+30) 
{
    price.setText("$" + Integer.toString(i));
}
```

Comment: So in your actual code you have a button somewhere...?

Comment: The problem is obvious. Where did you put this loop and how do you call it?

Comment: int i =49; i<9 is never true

Comment: Also, if this is inside a loop everything (or nothing in this case ) will be called inside a single on action call if setup to be executed when button clicked.

Comment: this is wrong , even this condition  int i =49;i<9;i=i+30 will always be false, and one more thing how clicking on button can be achieved through a for loop

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do you work in loop then do it like this.

```
 int firstval = 49;
 for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      System.out.println(Integer.toString(firstval += 30));
 }
```

ans will be like this

```
I/System.out: 79
I/System.out: 109
I/System.out: 139
I/System.out: 169
I/System.out: 199
I/System.out: 229
I/System.out: 259
I/System.out: 289
I/System.out: 319
```

or if you want to do with button click then

```
int firstval = 49;
button.setOnClickListener(v -> incValue());
private void incValue() {
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(firstval += 30));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add 30 on clicking plus button, first you need to add an `OnClickListner` on `Button`, the implementation will depend on which language you are using and then the actual code can be highlighted.

You can get the actual value in the listener callback function and then just add your defined value and set it, why you need to use the loop

```
public static final Integer INC_FACTOR = 30; // Increment factor

public onClickListner(Button ref) { // some dummy onClickListner
    ref.setLabel(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(ref.getLabel())+ INC_FACTOR));
}
```

Comment: @Ankur Please accept any answer if it solves your doubt, else comment for more information

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
public class counter {
    total = 0;

    userClicked() {
        total += 30;
    }
}
```